# Hyperlink,email address detection using camera

Tags: ios, augmented-reality

i want to build an app that recognizes hyperlinks and email addresses when i point out the camera at a paper or board which consists of lot of information along with hyperlinks and email addresses..anyway has anybody built such an app before or is it feasible? should i use augmented reality for this? what say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head the basic algorithm that first comes to mind is (1) capture the image, (2) process it via OCR looking for the particular strings you want, and (3) do what you want to do.

A quick search for "OCR on smartphone" turned up this paper which discusses OCR on smartphones and mentions an library available from Google, so you might start to get an overview there:

http://www.cs.unc.edu/cms/publications/honors-theses-1/lian09.pdf

The scenario you are describing does not sound like AR in a pure sense as you are not really "tracking" anything in the real world, but rather taking a picture and then post processing that image.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea. You will have to work with text recognition. For hyperlinks and email addresses you can create some rules for which specific features algorithm should look for("@","http://",..).

However text recognition(eventually text extraction with letter comparing in predefined font) is not easy. I don't really see how you would like to use AR. In fact this would be AR app, which would get such info from real world into digital form.

It would be great app but good luck :)